# How to remove items from an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, typescript

How to remove items from an array of objects?
There is an array of properties per which it is necessary to remove items from which isn isn coincides with the array.
Here is an example:

```
let selectedIsn = [10,15,20,30,40];
let arayObject = [{
  isn:10,
  name:"Bolt"
}, {
  isn:13,
  name:"marry"
},{
  isn:15,
  name:"a"
},{
  isn:18,
  name:"q"
}, {
  isn:20,
  name:"marrys"
},{
  isn:25,
  name:"aa"
},{
  isn:30,
  name:"qa"
}, {
  isn:40,
  name:"marrya"
},{
  isn:55,
  name:"sa"
},{
  isn:68,
  name:"qas"
 }];

let deleteSelected = (q,selectedItems) => {
        let arrayNew = q,
            count=0;

    for (var m = 0; m < q.length; m++) {
        let index = selectedItems.indexOf(q[m]["isn"]);
        if (index > -1) {
            arrayNew.splice(m - count, 1);
            count++;
        }
    }
    return arrayNew;
}

deleteSelected(arayObject,selectedIsn);
```

Removes not all elements of the given list. I do not understand what's wrong doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use filter like this

```
var result = arayObject.filter(item => selectedIsn.indexOf(item.isn)===-1);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.filter` function to get selected items from array

```
let deselected = arayObject.filter(function (a) {
   return selectedIsn.indexOf(a.isn) < 0;
});
```